# Swift Tableview

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

I have an array[13, 30, 15]. I want to show them in a tableview, just want to give different numbers with different string title showing in the tableview. Like:

```
Apple: 13
Banana: 30
Pear: 15
```

Are there any simple ways to realize it? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create one `Dictionary` like this `[Int : String]` and use this inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
var dict = [13 :"Apple", 30 : "Banana", 15 : "Pear"]
```

Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.label.text = dict[yourIntArray[indexPath.row]]
```

**Edit:**

As you mention in comment your have only 3 value and its order never change then make one string array in order that you want and use that array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
var stringArr = ["Apple","Banana","Pear"]
```

Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.label.text = stringArr[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Hi, could you please write a loop to set the String, because actually I will not know the number inside.

Comment: Can you say how you are going to differentiate the integer with its corresponding string?

Comment: Is you have other String array for that or something else?

Comment: I only have an array[Double], there are 3 numbers in it. I want to make the tableview like above. The String "Apple","Banana","Pear" will never change. And the order will not change, the first one number is for "Apple", the second one number is for "Banana".

Comment: Thank you for answering patiently. I actually want the string with number in the fixed order. Not only the string or only the number.

Comment: Can  you show what you want to display in the label? also, is your array[Double] value will be change?

Comment: Sure, I posted what I want in the question. String1:Number1, String2:Number2, String3:Number3. The only problem I did not clarify is I could not set the number into a dictionary, because actually I do not know what the numbers in array[Double] are. So I am looking for a loop to set the dictionary automatically.

Comment: Try like this `cell.label.text = "\(stringArr[indexPath.row]):\(array[indexPath.row])"`

Comment: Sorry, just Added.

Answer (score 2):

So You have an array of both the values, then you can use following:-

```
arrayInt[13, 30, 15]
arrayString["Apple","Banana","Pear"]
cell.label.text = "\(arrayString[indexPath.row]): \(arrayInt[indexPath.row])"
```

**Output becomes:-**

```
Apple: 13
Banana: 30
Pear: 15
```

Also, if you have just an array of int-values and stuck to show up then you could use:-

```
cell.label.text = "Your int values : \(arrayInt[indexPath.row])"
```

If you stuck with dynamic data then use following to append the data:-

```
arrayInt.append(newInt)
arrayString.append(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Associative Array.
2. Pass the string(Apple) as Key & Value() As Index

Comment: In Swift this is called a "dictionary".

Answer (score 0):

Use two arrays

var arraynumbers = [13,30,15]
var arraynames = [name1,name2,name3]

var string = "(arraynames[indexPath.row]): (arraynumbers[indexPath.row])"

cell.textlabel.text = string